# KIT KAT No Sound AS3 Test APKs

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, android-4.4-kitkat

**Re**: KIT KAT UPDATE (Samsung Galaxy Mega 6.3 MetroPCS)

**Tools**: Flash Professional CS6 Windows 7 x64 for Android

**GAME DEVELOPMENT | NO BACKGROUND SOUND**

I go ahead and update my phone (Mega 6.3) to Kit Kat 4.4.4 and when I install test APKs with background music in them the sound will not play in the device (I've yet to test effect sounds).

The background sound plays perfectly within the 'AIR debug launcher (desktop)' in my test APKs...no errors whatsoever but when I install the test APKs into my phone and run them...NO BACKGROUND SOUND. I hear that Kit Kat has issues with Flash and unfortunately I found this out too late.

**TECHNICAL**:

- Already installed latest Air APK and rebooted
- Already reinstalled the Kit Kat firmware for my device via ODIN
- Cannot install previous firmware due to the Kit Kat boot loader restrictions
- Installed modified version of Flash player

I tried 2 different types of codes...both play in the AIR desktop tester but not on my device.

**MY DEEP WISH RIGHT NOW**: To restore my Android back to Jelly Bean.

Here is one body of code I used...again it works in the desktop tester but not on my phone:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;

var snd = new Sound();
var src = new URLRequest("background.mp3");
var sndChannel;
var sndTrans = new SoundTransform();
sndTrans.volume = 0.5;
snd.load(src);
snd.addEventListener("complete", completeListener);
function completeListener(e)
{
    sndChannel = snd.play();
    sndChannel.soundTransform = sndTrans;
}
```

another code which works on the desktop debugger...not on phone:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var backSound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
backSound.load(new URLRequest ("background.mp3"));
myChannel = backSound.play(0,200);
```

REALITY HORROR:

The horror here is that whatever I develop for Android will most likely not work in other Kit Kat devices either.

KIT KAT IS A DARN SHAME

Comment: TEMPORARY SOLUTION - thanks all that have taken the time to read my issue...I found a temporary solution..I have to resort to the old method of dropping the actual sound file into a frame, then working its properties from there...this sucks big time and I only hope the issue gets resolved. I will also test this out via a class file and see what results that will render out.

Answer (score 0):

The method i use & What I would do in your case is Import your background.mp3 into your library.
make sure for the imported sounds library properties that you select 'import for actionscript' and create a class name on background.mp3. eg. 'backgroundSnd' 
Also Un-tick 'export to frame 1'.

create your function

```
function PlayBackgroundMP3(e:Event=null): void {
    var mysound:backgroundSnd = new backgroundSnd(); 
    mysound.play();
}
```

& then call sound function when wanted within your code:

```
PlayBackgroundMP3();
```

Comment: Great...I'll swing into that contribution thanks a whole million!

Answer (score 0):

WEIRD THINGS - the world must be coming to an end because I go and do another mobile app with background music using the standard coding method (no classes) and when I run it on my mobile phone the background music works...this is weird how I do the same exact thing initially and the first rendered apk doesn't work but the second project apk does...

...I really don't have time to examine the reason but if I have the issue again the I will certainly see what gives. My phone did not update either.